# What does the "opost" stty flag do?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, stty

The [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) says the following:

> [-]opost postprocess output

I don't understand what this means. I have tried to disable this flag to see what it does:

```
stty -opost -F /dev/pts/0
```

And I have typed the `ls` command, and the result had the first line indented:

[image]

I still don't get what this flag does!

Answer (score 6):

`stty -opost` deactivates post-processing output. For example, normally sending a <LF> (U+00A0) character to the terminal will automatically insert a <CR> (U+000D) character, to make the cursor go to the beginning of the next line. Most importantly, setting `-opost` deactivates *all* processing of output, irrespective of any other output options.

See the [manual page for `stty`(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/stty.1posix.html) for details.

Comment: So if for example the `ocrnl` is set, and I disable the `opost` flag, then the `ocrnl` flag will be ignored (also all other similar flags responsible for processing of output will be ignored)?

Comment: Why not try it out? `stty -opost ocrnl; echo -e 'aaa\nbbb'; stty sane`

Comment: While this is useful information, it is certainly not a comprehensive answer. E.g. I discovered that `opost` controls whether or not an LF after a full line of text is suppressed. E.g. for an 80 chars wide terminal, outputting 80 dots followed by an LF will not cause a blank line to appear if `opost` is set.

Comment: "deactivates the output processing" and the manual page all give the same (useless) information: That it suppresses output processing. The question is about what that output processing is.

Comment: The [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=functions-tcsetattr-set-attributes-terminal) gives a bit more detail. For options like `ONLCR` it says "If OPOST and ONLCR are set...". So turning off OPOST turns off ONLCR even if the ONLCR bit is set. Same goes for `ONOCR`, `OCRNL`, and `ONLRET`.